# Gradle include web.xml other web artifacts from other gradle project into war

Tags: gradle

How to include web artifacts under other.gradle into main.gradle when building war?

```
main.gradle    //Main Gradle
|_ _ /src/.../...
|_ _ other.gradle   //Included project
      |_ _ /WEB-INF/web.xml
      |_ _ /css
      |_ _ /js
```